# Tags diy and homemade seem to overlap

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Both currently have the same two questions: [diy](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) [homemade](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homemade)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. Merged / synonymized.

[home](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home) also needs to be cleaned up - actually, removed in most cases, but probably converted into [house](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house) in a few.